# Две Joomla на одном домене

Tags: joomla, php, .htaccess

Заказчик хотел, чтобы старый его сайт был доступен пользователям, пока не будет готов новый. Я создал папку и туда установил ещё одну джумлу. И там уже создавал новый сайт. Но, т.к. на сайте был ЧПУ (будь проклят тот, кто его придумал) если ходить по ссылкам нового сайта, то пишет `404 Not Found`, т.к. папку с новой джумлой воспринимает как категорию какого-нибудь материала, ибо страница ошибки была не обычная, а как раз она настраивается в плагине `Joom SEF`, который отвечает за ЧПУ. Как мне сделать, чтобы папка `newsi` определялась как папка, а не как категория материала? Но, кстати, главная страница открывается нормально. И да, что меня ещё больше разозлило, когда я убирал нафиг `.htacces` у старого сайта, ничего не менялось, по-прежнему если я заходил на "site.ru/newsi/test/art.html", то в адресной строке оставалась эта ссылка, а вот считывалось не `newsi/index.php`, а просто `index.php` (узнал я это по средствам тестов). Почему так? Я же отключил `htacces`.

**UPD:**
На сколько я понял дело в htacces, который лежит в папке newsi, там наверно идёт редирект на корневой index.php, но я вроде бы всё изменил, не должно:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/component/option,com) [NC,OR]
> ```
>
> ##опционально - смотрите примечания##
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|.htm|.php|.html|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
>     RewriteRule (.*) newsi/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему бы не создать поддомен для старого сайта? В этом случае htaccess нового не должен распространять правила на него. Как бы есть разница, если вы к старому обращаетесь так - **http://newsite.ru/oldsite/** и так - **http://oldsite.newsite.ru/**

Comment: Да мне от панели управления не дали доступ, а если просить, то только через день-два дадут, а я уезжаю, нужно срочно доделать. А вообще идея хорошая.